# Find site URL from SharePoint GUID

Tags: sharepoint, url, guid

I am analyzing ADFS logs, which reference the SharePoint webs visited (via the wcontext parameter) but do so via their GUID.

How do I translate a SharePoint site/web GUID into a URL?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct correlation between a GUID and a URL.

If you are looking for this information from a code-behind, you could get the SPWeb object from the GUID, and poll the .URL property from there.

~ED

Comment: Thank you, that sounds reasonable. No, I'm analyzing the logs away from SharePoint, but the set of GUIDs is quite reasonable, and I presume I can write a PowerShell script to resolve the small set.

Michael

Comment: Try 
stsadm -o enumallwebs
If you have a set of sensible Content Database names - you should be able to match site GUID to content database, and thus, site collection.

stsadm -o enumallwebs gives a detailed list of what subsites are found in a content database as well, each paired with it's GUID. You could conceivably pipe the output to an xml file for review.

Answer (score 0):

I used SharePoint Manager 2010 to find the GUID of a site I found in the event log. You can download it from [spm.codeplex.com](http://spm.codeplex.com/)